# Android Substratum change brightness & volume bars

Tags: android, theming

I try to make a substratum theme because I'd like to change the volume and brightness bar to make it look like this :
[My project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAj6N.png)

But here we'll focus on brightness

So I must make a substratum theme for `com.android.systemui`. I pulled the SystemUI.apk, decompiled it with apktool, opened it in Android Studio.

In the res/layout folder I found the xml which manages the brightness bar, `quick_settings_brightness_dialog.xml`

[Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k17R.png)

The problem is that as you can see in the screenshot the brightness bar isn't here directly, instead there is this element:

```
<com.android.systemui.settings.ToggleSliderView
        android:id="@id/brightness_slider"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="48.0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:contentDescription="@string/accessibility_brightness"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        android:paddingLeft="-4.0dip"
        android:paddingRight="-4.0dip"
        systemui:text="@string/status_bar_settings_auto_brightness_label" />
```

The problem is that I don't know what is `com.android.systemui.settings.ToggleSliderView` and where to find it to modify it. Could somebody help me please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do this went in res/drawable folder and found ic_brightness_thumb to hide the little sun, and brightness_progress_drawable.xmlto play with the bar width